# How to interact and set DOM properties with WebSharper?

Tags: javascript, dom, f#, websharper

I often need to interact with my page's DOM, how can I do it via WebSharper?

For instance when I want to redirect my page in just JavaScript I'd run:

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
```

How can I access `window` and set `location`? how would this look in F#?
Also, how would it work with functions, for instance with IE's:

```
window.navigate("http://www.google.com/")
```

*Note: If there is a built-in way to redirect via WebSharper I'd love to know it but keep in mind this is just an example.*

Comment: Check the [`IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Dom`](http://www.websharper.com/extensions/dom) namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `window.location` property after opening the `IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Html5` namespace which provides support for the standard HTML5 APIs. In order to navigate using the location object you can call the `assign` or `replace` methods:

```
Window.Self.Location.Assign "http://www.google.com/"
```

A live demo is available [here](http://wssnippets.apphb.com/snippet/19).

For vendor specific functions you can inline the JavaScript and use it as if it was built into WebSharper:

```
[<Inline "window.navigate($uri)">]
let ieNavigate uri = X<unit>
```

Comment: That's great, but **when using `Inline`**, how would I pass data? (say if the script should redirect to a page whose path is only known in run-time).

Comment: Just add a parameter to the function, I updated the code accordingly.