# How can we get Current Page URL in F#, Websharper

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#, websharper

How can we get Current Page URL in F#, Websharper.

e.g we do it in c#

> string PageUrl = Request.Url.ToString();

It is very simple for expert people i just want to get current page url with querystring complete url

```
> e.g. http://localhost:58496/default.aspx?id=434
```

Comment: do you want to get this on the server or on the client side? On the server-site it's just `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` (just like in C# ;) ) - on the client side you could use `window.location` (see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22406680/how-to-interact-and-set-dom-properties-with-websharper)

Comment: It's worth noting that MVC maps some of the `HttpContext.Current` properties to the `Controller` base class.

Comment: @CarstenKönig your method working properly.